# Trouble binding keyboard shortcuts in extension for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to develop a Visual Studio 2013 Add-In / Extension Package and I'm having some trouble trying to understand why my commands don't work.

I'm binding keys to my command like it's shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138531(v=vs.120).aspx):

```
    <KeyBindings>
        <KeyBinding guid="guidMyPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidMyCommand" key1="C" mod1="CONTROL" mod2="ALT" editor="guidVSStd97" />
    </KeyBindings>
```

But the command is not getting recognized when I press it, and in TOOLS menu only "Ctl + C" is displayed next to my command name.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with C# or .NET, does it?

Comment: Well, I am developing the extension in C#... I guess what .net language I'm using in particular is irrelevant for the case in point. Thanks for the useful correction.